# SSIS removing single quote within double quotes

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am attempting to create a **derived column** that will remove single quotes surrounding a string that is also contained within double quotes. For example:

```
"Robert 'Bob' LaBla"
```

I need to remove just the single quotes around *Bob* so that the outcome is:

```
"Robert Bob LaBla"
```

Tried `REPLACE(Column,"\"","")` which removes the double quotes perfectly but replacing this expression with single quotes doesn't seem to work. I'd rather not have to write a script for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove single quotes in derived column just use the following expression:

```
REPLACE(Column,"'","")
```

If you need to remove both quotes then

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(Column,"\"",""),"'","")
```

**References**

- [how to replace quotation marks in a derived column?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b62fd59e-8732-4055-91c0-fdc3c24de342/how-to-replace-quotation-marks-in-a-derived-column?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [REPLACE (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)